# Images positioned differently in Safari

Tags: browser, compatibility

My page is tomblex.com.

There is a green vector ribbon which is positioned differently in Safari.

I was going to use PHP to make a separate stylesheet but I thought that might be very difficult, so I thought I might first ask here.

This is the HTML code that displays differently:

```
<div style="position:relative;top: -192;left:-541;"id="wrapper">
  <img style="position:absolute;width:1083;height:77px;"
       src="http://www.tomblex.com/leengchoste.png">
</div>
```

Comment: <div style="position:relative;top: -192;left:-541;"id="wrapper">
<img style="position:absolute;width:1083;height:77px;"src="http://www.tomblex.com/leengchoste.png">
</div>

Comment: I find it kind off Ironic that whenever I ask a question that doesn't specify every last detail people refuse to answer however when I actually do what you ask me nobody even answers at all.